# If first element in array do something else

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array in which if it's the first element, I have to calculate using a different formula compared to the rest of the elements in the array. Issue is that the loop only enters the if condition and doesn't enter the else condition.

Not sure if I am doing this right.

Here's the code:

```
var days = 535; //user selection
var val = 3;    //user selection
var baseDays = 182.5;
var someValArr_1 = [12,16,23,31,33,34,39,45,49,54,59,62,62,so on]; //same for 2 other arrays

var someValArrDiff_1 = diff(someValArr_1); //function to subtract two consecutive elements in array

var noOfDays =[182.5,365,547.5,730,912.5,so on];

var arrayLength = noOfDays.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if(noOfDays[i] == noOfDays[0]) { //182.5
        switch(val) {
            case 1:
                discount = days/noOfDays[i] * someValArrDiff_1[i];
                break;
            case 2:
                discount = days/noOfDays[i] * someValArrDiff_2[i];
                break;
            case 3:
                discount = days/noOfDays[i] * someValArrDiff_3[i];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        if(noOfDays[i] < days && days < noOfDays[i+1]){

            switch(val) {
                case 1:
                    discount = (days-noOfDays[i]) * someValArrDiff[i+1]/baseDays + someValArr_1[i];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    discount = (days-noOfDays[i]) * someValArrDiff_2[i+1]/baseDays + someValArr_2[i];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    discount = (days-noOfDays[i]) * someValArrDiff_3[i+1]/baseDays + someValArr_3[i];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("Discount " +discount);
    return discount;
}
```

I tried `if(days < noOfDays[0])` but this skips the if-else condition altogether and returns 0.

Comment: Why not just `if (i == 0)` ?

Comment: Did that, but it returns 0. It doesn't enter the else condition if the first one is false.

Comment: Where is days declaration?

Comment: @Jules, I edited the code. It is a user input value though. It changes depending on the value the user has input.

Comment: we also don't see where `val` and `car` come from. There is something you are not showing us.

Comment: what is your val in switch??

Comment: @CharlieNg, I have updated the code. Please check.

Comment: @OliviaRuth, I have updated the code.

Comment: val = 6, switch goes to default and no calculation is done. Working as intended :)

Comment: Apologies @Jules, I'm half asleep. It should be 3. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I took out the calculation and put debugging trace on "if" and "else" condition.  Only the "if" is executed, the "else" is not executed.  I think this is an issue with your program logic/data.

Comment: I don't get it.  You have a loop but you aren't summing discount so I guess it's being recalculated and overwritten as the loop progresses.   Wait you return after iterating once, that seems like a bug. Are you wanting to do one calculation for discount or sum a series of calculations?

Comment: @James, I am doing one calculation for a discount. I'm checking the variable `days` which `noOfDays` range it falls into and calculating the formula accordingly and then returning the discount. If I remove the first `if-else` condition, it calculates the discount correctly, but I want to use a different formula for the first element in the array and that's where I'm stuck currently.

Comment: @James, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. `Wait you return after iterating once, that seems like a bug.` --This was the issue. Can you please post your comment as answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code `i` will be set to the index of the first element in the array greater than `days`.

```js
var days = 535;
var noOfDays =[182.5,365,547.5,730,912.5];

var i = 0;
while (days > noOfDays[i]) i++;

if (i == 0) {
  // do your calculation for days <= 182.5
} else {
  // do your calculation for days between noOfDays[i-1] and noOfDays[i]
}
```

This would remove the bug you had (returning after iterating a loop once) and remove the need to unnecessarily calculate discounts for everything up to i, which get discarded.

Comment: Thank you for this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

well, looks like you solved the problem but logically this is something you need to fix.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
```

should be

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength - 1; i++) {
```

because the statement below will compare 535 with undefined

```
if(noOfDays[i] < days && days < noOfDays[i+1]){
```

The second thing is you can safely change

```
if(noOfDays[i] == noOfDays[0])
```

to

```
if(i === 0)
```